# Using Raycast to see if canvas button clicked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get the button using this:

```
Button button = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCanvas").GetComponentInChildren<Button>();
```

And then I do:

```
void Update()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, hit))
    {       
        if (button.collider.Raycast(mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), hit))
        { 
            //Code to run when button clicked
        }
    }   
}
```

However I keep getting errors on this. Any idea where I've gone wrong?

Error:

```
Argument 1: Cannot convert from UnityEngine.Ray to UnityEngine.Vector3 Argument 1: Cannot convert from UnityEngine.RaycastHit to UnityEngine.Vector3 Component.collider is obsolete. Property: collider has been depricated Component does not contain a definition for Raycast and no extension method 'Raycast' accepting a first argument type of 'Component' could be found
```

Comment: What kind of error do you got there?

Comment: Argument 1: Cannot convert from UnityEngine.Ray to UnityEngine.Vector3 Argument 1: Cannot convert from UnityEngine.RaycastHit to UnityEngine.Vector3

Component.collider is obsolete. Property: collider has been depricated

Component does not contain a definition for Raycast and no extension method 'Raycast' accepting a first argument type of 'Component' could be found

Comment: Why did someone spend time correcting my grammar but not helping the question?

Comment: @zligg because he does not know the answer, but can correct it to help someone who know the answer to better understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Its because there is no such a field as `Button.collider`. The compiler has no idea what field you are trying to access. It also is saying that that field has been deprecated so there you go